# Input validation error not showing to user

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have this in my action to validate an ajax post

```
if(Yii::$app->request->isAjax && $model->load(Yii::$app->request->post())){
    Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
     return ActiveForm::validate($model);
}
```

in my view

```
<?php
    $form = ActiveForm::begin([
        'id' => $model->formName().'-form',
        'action' => Url::to(['/payment/stripe/payment-session']),
        'scrollToError' => false,
        'validateOnSubmit' => true,
        'enableAjaxValidation' => true
    ]); 

    echo $form->field($model, 'number')->textInput([ 'class' => 'form-control form-control-lg text-uppercase', 'placeholder'=>'Enter Number', 'id' => 'reports-number'])->label(false);
    ....
    ....
    ActiveForm::end();
                            
?>
```

in my model

```
public function rules() {

...
[['number'], ENumberValidator::class, 'on' => ['check-number']],
...
}
```

when i enter `456!!` in the input, i get this ajax returned. which is correct.

```
{
    "reports-number": [
        "Number is an invalid format."
    ]
}
```

**but** for some reason no error message shows under the input, the input has a check mark in green and form can still be submitted. Any idea what I'm missing here? Thanks

Comment: try to remove `'id' => 'reports-number'`, as far as I remember the id generated with a form and JS use it

Comment: Have you tried to return to the view in your action?

Something like $this->renderAjax('yourView',['model'=>$yourModel]);